# Retrieve content while app is not active iOS delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

How can I check for new server content in background on iOS/Android using Delphi Xe8. I understand how to update the iconbadgecount and even adding the correct .PLIST keys ( for iOS ) via http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/10/providing-background-services-support-to-your-ios-apps-with-delphi/ but beyond that, I'm not quite sure what to do next.